# How much reputation is needed to see deleted questions, and is there a way to permanently delete them?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

If I delete my own question:

1. How much reputation is needed for normal users to see it?
2. Can I undelete my own question?
3. How can I permanently delete my own question?

Comment: Edit my question title. I am asking about my deleted questions actually not asnwers.

Answer (score 3):

1. 10k. It's not actually that easy to find deleted questions - you can't search for them. You either have to have a direct link to the question, or hunt through the reports. This is by design - deleted questions are meant to be kinda-sorta unfindable.
2. Click the `undelete` button just below your question text.
3. You can't. Well, you might be able to convince the site admins to, by emailing them at the address at the bottom of the page. I don't think even mods can do this.

Comment: Re your answer to 2: Assuming you can find it of course!

Comment: @ChrisF: You can't view your own deleted questions after you navigate away from them unless you have 10k.

Comment: @Simon - that was my point - there are no links to deleted questions so you'd have to have bookmarked the URL outside of SO.

Comment: @ChrisF: Even if you had the link, you still couldn't view it (I recently tested it).

Comment: @Simon - you can view your own deleted questions in the same way you can see your own deleted answers if you go back to the relevant question. You just need to have the link referenced somewhere *outside* of SO